# show branches and commits for local (non pushed) state

Tags: tortoisegit

In Tortoise Git, one can see commits and branches in the log, like here:

[image]

I'd like to see the same also in my local state, i.e. what I have done on my computer but not pushed. But I can't see it. Is that possible?

I created a new branch "testbranch" from the selected state in branch "master", then did one commit ("test commit") in testbranch. This is what I expected to see in the graph:

[image]

But instead I can only find views of single branches ("master" and "testbranch").

Branch "master":

[image]

Branch "testbranch":

[image]

How can I see both branches and their commits together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select "All branches" in the lower left or click on the branch name in the upper left and select alls branches that you want to see in the Reference Browser.

cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-showlog.html

Comment: I tried that as well, but it just looked like the "testbranch". I figured that it does not show the branching if it does not need to. After doing another commit on "master" branch, I finally could see the branch branching off and the two commits in the different branches.